# where to ask about switch servers OS?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [why some switch OS are solaries?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34411/why-some-switch-os-are-solaries)

where i can ask my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *consider* asking this on https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com, but you really should read their help centers first to check what's on topic. Most likely the way you posed the question here, it won't be accepted on any stack echange because it only leads to opinion based answers.